Quiero utilizar una ventana para avisarle al usuario que ya se descargo el pdf
Tengo el siguiente código en .NET, lo que sucede es que si me funciona el audio pero no me esta saliendo la ventana que dice YA DESCARGASTE EL PDF :D
Intente hacer un evento donde después de que el archivo pdf se descarga, o reproduzca el sonido, quiero que salga un popout una ventana emergente que contenga una imagen.
Use un enfoque que combina la reproducción del sonido en el servidor y la actualización de la página en el cliente mediante JavaScript.
Aqui esta el back
//Acciones de botones
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = (Button)sender;
    if (b.Text == "Imprimir..")
    {
        this.Guardar();
        DescargarPDF();   
    }
    this.inicializaPagina(b.Text);

    // Si el botón no es de imprimir, entonces inicializar la página

}


protected void DescargarPDF()
{
    string id = (string)ViewState["idRegistro"];
    string filePath = $"~/FILES/CONSTANCIA_IMP_{id}.pdf";
    string absolutePath = Server.MapPath(filePath);

    if (File.Exists(absolutePath))
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename=CONSTANCIA_IMP_{id}.pdf");
        Response.TransmitFile(absolutePath);
        Response.Flush();

        string soundPath = Server.MapPath("~/sounds/sound.wav");
        PlaySound(soundPath);



        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup", "showPopup();", true);
        Response.End();

    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("El archivo no está disponible.");
        Response.End();
    }
}

private void PlaySound(string path)
{
    using (System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(path))
    {
        player.Play();
    }
}


Aqui esta el UI
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Impresion.aspx.cs" Inherits="BURO_VEH.Impresion.Impresion.Impresion" EnableEventValidation="false" %>
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
<%@ register assembly="GMaps" namespace="Subgurim.Controles" tagprefix="cc1" %>





<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr><asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenFieldDatos" runat="server"/>
            <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #AE9976; color:white; font-size: large">
              <asp:Label ID="LabelTitulo" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    </table>


<div id="activity_pane">

        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>    
 
<asp:Table ID="TablePrincipal" runat="server" Border=0 Width="100%">
           <asp:TableRow> 
                       <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlign="Center" >  
                                      <asp:Panel ID="PanelGRID" runat="server" BorderStyle="NotSet" >
                                      <asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="GridView_SelectedIndexChanged" onrowdatabound="GridView_RowDataBound" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView_PageIndexChanged"/>
                                     </asp:Panel>
                                   
                       </asp:TableCell>      
           </asp:TableRow>
           <asp:TableRow > 
                       <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="1" Width="80%" >  
                            <asp:Panel ID="PanelDATOS" runat="server" BorderStyle="NotSet"  ScrollBars="Auto">
                                   <asp:Table ID="TableDATOS" runat="server" Border=0></asp:Table>
                               
                            </asp:Panel> 
                       </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="1">  
                            <asp:Panel ID="PanelDatos2" runat="server" BorderStyle="NotSet" >
                                   <asp:Table ID="TableDatos2" runat="server" Border=0></asp:Table>
                            </asp:Panel>
                         </asp:TableCell>
                       
          </asp:TableRow> 
    
</asp:Table>
  
    <br />
   
   <asp:Button ID="ButtonGuardar" runat="server" Text="" OnClientClick="return validaAltaModificacion();" onclick="Button_Click" />
    
<asp:Label ID="LabelResultadoProceso" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

 <br />
     
    

</div>
  
    
    <script src="../../Scripts/Validaciones.js" type="text/javascript" language="Javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/Valida.js" type="text/javascript" language="Javascript"></script>  
    <script src="../../Scripts/Valida_FG.js" type="text/javascript" language="Javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.showLoading.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></!--script-->
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function rotate2(ID, value) {
            value = $('[id*=Hiddenfalse_ROTAR' + ID.split('_')[1] + ']').val();//document.getElementById('MainContent_Hiddenfalse_ROTAR' + ID + '_UNO').value;
            //  alert(ID);
            // alert($('[id*=Hiddenfalse_ROTAR' + ID + ']').val());
            //   alert(value);
            value = (value * 1) + 90;
            if (value > 270)
                value = 0;
            //  alert($('[id*=general_' + ID + ']').attr('id'));

            var idTmp = $('[id*=' + ID + ']').attr('id')
            document.getElementById(idTmp).style.webkitTransform = "rotate(" + value + "deg)";
            document.getElementById(idTmp).style.msTransform = "rotate(" + value + "deg)";
            document.getElementById(idTmp).style.transform = "rotate(" + value + "deg)";
            //document.getElementById('span1').innerHTML = value + "deg";

            // document.getElementById('MainContent_Hiddenfalse_ROTAR' + ID + '_UNO').value = value;
            $('[id*=Hiddenfalse_ROTAR' + ID.split('_')[1] + ']').val(value);

        }



        function showPopup() {
            const popup = document.createElement("div");
            popup.style.position = "fixed";
            popup.style.left = "50%";
            popup.style.top = "50%";
            popup.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -50%)";
            popup.style.padding = "20px";
            popup.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            popup.style.boxShadow = "0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
            popup.innerHTML = `<img src="~/Imagenes/descargacompleta1.jpg" alt="Popup Image" style="max-width: 100%;">`;

            const closeButton = document.createElement("button");
            closeButton.innerText = "Close";
            closeButton.style.marginTop = "10px";
            closeButton.onclick = () => document.body.removeChild(popup);
            popup.appendChild(closeButton);

            document.body.appendChild(popup);
        }
    </script>


    </script>
   


    </script>
     
</asp:Content>


Espero que salga una ventana con una imagen que dice que ya se termino de descargar la imagen.
Solo sucede la reproducción del sonido la ventana no aparece.
Me podrían ayudar :D o tiene otra idea de como lo puedo hacer.
También no se porque pero la pantalla se queda así después de que descarga el archivo

